# Showing wrong URL in search bar in Browser because of Servlet while navigating among login,logout,index page

Tags: jsp, url, servlets

What I want to learn is to fix URL problem by navigating among pages.

When I login in the login page (`http://localhost:1112/BookStoreWebsiteProject/backend/login.jsp`), it opens index.jsp but its url address is shown as `http://localhost:1112/BookStoreWebsiteProject/backend/login` .

When I logout in the index jsp whose url address is defined as `http://localhost:1112/BookStoreWebsiteProject/backend/login`, it opens login forum whose url address `http://localhost:1112/BookStoreWebsiteProject/backend/logout`

Login Servlet

```
@WebServlet("/backend/login")
public class AdminLoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
String page = "/backend/";
             RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
             requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Logout Servlet

```
@WebServlet("/backend/logout")
public class AdminLogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
String page = "login.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Home Servlet

```
@WebServlet("/backend/")
public class AdminHomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
...

String page = "index.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: When I open the index.jsp after login.jsp , url is shown as /backend/index.jsp. When I logout from index jsp, url is shown as backend/login.jsp

Comment: and you want the url to show what after you logout?

Comment: you hit the nail on the head. How can I design url part

Comment: okay but you need to clarify exactly what you want the url to show after you login and after you logout, then i will show you how you can achieve it

Comment: login page to index.jsp (login process ) -> http://localhost:1112/BookStoreWebsiteProject/backend/login.jsp. -> http://localhost:1112/BookStoreWebsiteProject/backend/index.jsp.                               index.jsp to login page (logout process) . http://localhost:1112/BookStoreWebsiteProject/backend/index.jsp -> http://localhost:1112/BookStoreWebsiteProject/backend/login.jsp

Comment: after logging in you want the url to be /login.jsp  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about designing the url part. Normally this is done with the use of Java Filters. In your case, you can do something like this with `response.sendRedirect`:

**Login Servlet**

> /backend/login --> backend/index.jsp

```
@WebServlet("/backend/login")
public class AdminLoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
String page = "/index.jsp";
response.sendRedirect(page);
```

**Logout Servlet**

> /backend/logout --> backend/logout.jsp

```
@WebServlet("/backend/logout")
public class AdminLogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
String page = "logout.jsp";
response.sendRedirect(page);
```

**Home Servlet**

> Note you should do this part in your web.xml

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 1):

My Answer

```
String page = request.getContextPath() + "/backend/login.jsp";
response.sendRedirect(page);

String page = request.getContextPath() + "/backend/logout.jsp";
response.sendRedirect(page);

String page = request.getContextPath() + "/backend/index.jsp";
response.sendRedirect(page);
```